# Optional function parameter Java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a way of makeing optional parameter in java.

for my experience in other programing languages there is an option to write function prototype like that:
`int foo(int num = 0)`
and if i call the func `foo()` the var `num` will be equal to `0`.

I've been looking over the internet and its seem to be not exists in java.

Comment: No it doesn't exist in Java, if you want similar behavior you need to overload the method: create a version of the method that required no parameters and calls the other version of the method with a default parameter. (eG. `public int foo() { return foo(0);}`)

Comment: Have you considered [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Varargs should fulfill your request here.
Call method without passing any arguments or pass null parameter:-
foo(null) or foo().

Your method signature:-

```
void foo(String... name){//Business logic}
```